# Is MethodChannel buffering messages until the other side is "connected"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I have a `MethodChannel` on the Android side:

```
    class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
      private var channel : MethodChannel? = null

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        channel = MethodChannel(flutterView, "com.foo.Bar")

        channel!!.invokeMethod("onCreate", "created")
      }
    }
```

On the Dart side, I do:

```
    void main() {
      _main();
    }

    Future<void> _main() async {
      ... // do some async init stuff


      const platform = MethodChannel('com.foo.Bar');
      platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
        print('com.foo.Bar');
        print(call.method);
        print(call.arguments);
        return null;
      });

      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

When running the code, I don't see the respective messages in the application log.

Is `MethodChannel` on the Android side buffering messages until the Dart side is "connected" or is the message sent in `MainActivity.onCreate`?

Comment: Some time ago i had a similar problem. I might be wrong, but i thought that the problem is not actually in buffering, but that MethodChannel on a Dart side is not created yet, when the message is already sent from Android side.
So my workaround was to save data on Android side and then when you need the data on Dart's side make a call to Android

Comment: That’s what I meant with “not buffering”...

Answer (score 1):

Even if the question is a bit older, I found myself in a similar situation.

I have used the `android.intent.action.VIEW` Intent Filter to allow my app to open files. More precise, I wanted to hand over the content of the opened file to the dart code for processing.

Since opening a File starts the app, the method call was would be invoked, before the dart part has build the widget tree and created the Method Channel.

Therefore, the Native Android Part needs to wait until the Dart Part is ready. 
This can be Achieve by listening to the renderer.

Since the code should be readable use a extension on the FlutterRenderer to increase code readability:

```
fun FlutterRenderer.doAfterFirstRender(op: () -> Unit){

    // Check if flutter part is already available
    if (isDisplayingFlutterUi) {
        op()
    } else {
        addIsDisplayingFlutterUiListener(object :FlutterUiDisplayListener{
            override fun onFlutterUiNoLongerDisplayed() {
            }

            override fun onFlutterUiDisplayed() {
                removeIsDisplayingFlutterUiListener(this)
                op()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Within the code you can now easily invoke the method using the extension:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

        // Check if the intent was from file
        if (intent.action != null
                && intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                && intent.data != null) {


            // get the file name & content
            val fileName = getFileName(intent.data)
            val fileExtension = fileName.orEmpty().split('.').last().toLowerCase()

            // check if the file extension is allowed
            if (fileExtension in ALLOWED_FILE_EXTENSIONS) {

                // get the file content
                val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(
                        context.contentResolver.openInputStream(intent.data)))
                val content = reader.readText()
                reader.close()

                val methodName = when (fileExtension) {
                    "ixml" -> "importDataFile"
                    "gxml" -> "importStructureFile"
                    else -> ""
                }

               flutterEngine.renderer.doAfterFirstRender {
                   MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, IMPORT_FILE_CHANNEL)
                           .invokeMethod(methodName, content)
               }
            }
        }
    }
```